# Meaning of a line in 'Story of my life' by One direction. ''I spend her love until she's broke, inside''

Tags: lyrics, meaning

I want to ask two things.

1. He spends her love.
   Does it signify that **he casually spend/consumed her love, took her for granted**? 
   Or that **he loved her as much as she did loved him**?.
2. Why is the the girl broke?
   Is it **'because she loves him so much that she gives him all her love until she has no more left, so 'she becomes broke'(on her own)**?
   Or is it that **she gives him all her love and he takes all her love, consumes all her love and that's why 'he got her broke'**?

Or am I wrong in interpreting both ways? I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [annotation](https://genius.com/2379446) on [Genius.com](https://genius.com/) for the chorus of the song reads as follows:

> The love he finally receives from her is spent (possibly on another girl?) and now she feels abused because the boy had given her hope for a real relationship, and that’s been the story of his life, always creating a sustainable connection then tearing it down.
>
> He has become a guy who gets close and never keeps the connection alive, taking a toll on those who want to love him and those he wants to love.

The [description/overview of the lyrics](https://genius.com/One-direction-story-of-my-life-lyrics) contains more insight into the meaning of the song:

> The song is about a love story gone bad: in the first verses, in fact, the main character thinks about the break-up with a girl whom really loved.
> In the hook, the story changes: the boy, who can’t have the true love of her life (because she broke up with him), just passes from one girl to another, trying to convince them and himself that he does love them, but he realizes that he can’t forget the love of his life, who is the one that he can’t have, as well.

Comment: Hmm... So the guy **did** love his girl but **spend the love he got from his girl** possibily on another girl and that's how got **his girl** broke. Right?

Comment: @Nikki That seems to be what the annotation says. Obviously it's up to interpretation since it's not an entirely clear phrase. Really the only way to know what the lyrics mean is to ask the writers of the song what they meant by it; otherwise all we can really do is speculate.

Comment: I agree. Different sites have different explainations for it. Thanks for helping, it gave me a new perspective for the lyrics.. I might not fully accept it(maybe in future I will) but I've upvoted your answer. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

"Broke" was used as in this sentence - "I've spent so much money, now I'm broke".

**I spend her love until she's broke** *Inside*

The way "inside" was used was to infer that the usage did not imply money, but love.

**..*Broke*..**

A way to exaggerate how much love she gave him, *in fact he got so much love from her **she got broke** inside -- Exaggeration noted here *